# connecting points with a reasonable solution

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on a python project
the objective ob this project is connect the red points to the blue points, the red and blue points are given by the problem
[the given problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWLbn.png)

the result should be something like this
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzl1b.png)
I'm looking for an idea for problem
the solution should work for any similar cases

I did try these following method which I choose the first point and get the closest blue point, but this situation can happen
[The left is when I pick the correct first point, right is if I pick wrong point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvQdD.png)

I could check if the connecting line are intersect and revese the order, but again the following situation can happen
[The connecting line can potentially parallel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWXQn.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you coud take the coords of the blue points (x_i,y_i) where i is the point number and the red points (u_j,v_j) and calculate every posible distance : for every j for every i: d_ij and find de minimal distance for every i (wich j is closer) the pair ij with minimun distance is the one you have to draw a line

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, you are dealing with an [Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem#:%7E:text=If%20the%20total%20cost%20of,problem%20is%20called%20linear%20assignment.). You can use [scipy's linear_sum_assignment](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html) with a distance matrix as the cost matrix. In other words, you want the combination of red and blue points that yields the smaller total distance (sum of distances between connected points).

```py
import numpy as np 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

n_points = 5

np.random.seed(10)
blue_points = np.random.random((2, n_points))
red_points = np.random.random((2, n_points))

# Calculate distance matrix 
distance_matrix = np.linalg.norm(blue_points[:,:,np.newaxis] - red_points[:, np.newaxis,:], axis=0)

# Solve the assignment problem
blue_i, red_i = linear_sum_assignment(distance_matrix)

pairs = list(zip(blue_i, red_i))
# Plot 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(*blue_points,'bo')
ax.plot(*red_points,'ro')
for i, j in pairs: 
    blue_points.shape
    x = [blue_points[0, i], red_points[0, j]]
    y = [blue_points[1, i], red_points[1, j]]
    ax.plot(x,y, 'k')
```

[image]